# Pandas: join individual start / end columns into a single row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of start/stop times, with each start/stop time on a separate row. I need to associate each starttime with its corresponding stoptime. The basic algorithm is this:

```
for each starttime:
    find nearest future stoptime if it exists
```

Constraints:

- initial start times may not be present, in which case the `starttime` should read `None`
- final stop times may also not be present, in which case the `stoptime` should read `None`

Example input:

```
y = pd.DataFrame([[None, '2020-08-04'], ['2020-10-23', None], ['2020-11-05', None], ['2020-11-14', None], [None, '2020-11-13'], [None, '2020-10-29']], columns=['starttime', 'stoptime'])

    starttime    stoptime
0        None  2020-08-04
1  2020-10-23        None
2  2020-11-05        None
3  2020-11-14        None
4        None  2020-11-13
5        None  2020-10-29
```

Desired output:

```
    starttime    stoptime
0        None  2020-08-04
1  2020-10-23  2020-10-29
2  2020-11-05  2020-11-13
3  2020-11-14        None
```

There's a lot of data here, so ideally there's a vectorized Pandas solution.

Comment: Is there no identifier as far as who or what initialized the start/stop? So in other words, group the closest time start, to its closest time stop starting from oldest timestamp?

Comment: Does your data only contains these two columns ? any other column which can be used as a key identifier to relate start and stop time.

Comment: No other identifiers are available, nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
y = pd.DataFrame([[None, '2020-08-04'], ['2020-10-23', None], ['2020-11-05', None], ['2020-11-14', None], [None, '2020-11-13'], [None, '2020-10-29']], columns=['starttime', 'stoptime'])

y['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(y['starttime'], errors='coerce')
y['stoptime'] = pd.to_datetime(y['stoptime'], errors='coerce')

df_1 = pd.merge_asof(left=y['starttime'].dropna(), 
          right=y['stoptime'].dropna().sort_values(), 
          left_on='starttime', right_on='stoptime',
         direction='forward')
df_2 = y[~y['stoptime'].isin(df_1['stoptime'])]

result = pd.concat([df_2, df_1], ignore_index=True)
result
```

output:

```
    starttime   stoptime
0   NaT         2020-08-04
1   2020-10-23  2020-10-29
2   2020-11-05  2020-11-13
3   2020-11-14  NaT
```

Comment: My first thought was merge.as_of as well. This seems correct but it doesn't work when I run it - I'm getting `*** ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: Got it to work with `to_frame()` on the left= and right= arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you can be certain that your data won't be missing any start or stop points except the first and last? That is, if you arranged all your example times in one sequence, they would alternate: start, stop, start, and so on. Is your actual data guaranteed to follow this pattern?

If so, you don't actually have to do any thorough comparison between the two columns. You only need to:

1. Remove each column's `None` values.
2. Sort each column.
3. Compare only the *first* value from each column. If the earliest start time is later than the earliest stop time, the start times need to be shifted down by one.
4. Combine into a dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

times = pd.DataFrame([[None, '2020-08-04'], ['2020-10-23', None],
                      ['2020-11-05', None], ['2020-11-14', None],
                      [None, '2020-11-13'], [None, '2020-10-29']],
                      columns=['starttime', 'stoptime'])

# Remove empty values and sort each column.
starttime = times.starttime.dropna().sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
stoptime = times.stoptime.dropna().sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)

if starttime[0] > stoptime[0]:
    # Lengthen and shift starttimes, if necessary.
    starttime.loc[max(starttime.index)+1] = None
    starttime = starttime.shift()

matched_times = pd.concat([starttime, stoptime], axis=1)
print(matched_times)
```

```
    starttime    stoptime
0         NaN  2020-08-04
1  2020-10-23  2020-10-29
2  2020-11-05  2020-11-13
3  2020-11-14         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
y = pd.DataFrame([[None, '2020-08-04'], ['2020-10-23', None], ['2020-11-05', None], ['2020-11-14', None], [None, '2020-11-13'], [None, '2020-10-29']], columns=['starttime', 'stoptime'])
print('raw data:')
print(y)

    #    starttime    stoptime
    # 0        None  2020-08-04
    # 1  2020-10-23        None
    # 2  2020-11-05        None
    # 3  2020-11-14        None
    # 4        None  2020-11-13
    # 5        None  2020-10-29

print('#' * 50)    
df1 = y['starttime'].dropna().to_frame()
df1['tag'] = 1
df2 = y['stoptime'].dropna().to_frame()
df2['tag'] = 2

df1.columns = ['time', 'tag']
df2.columns = ['time', 'tag']

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df3.sort_values('time', inplace=True)
print('merge starttime & stoptime with tag')
print(df3)

    #          time  tag
    # 0  2020-08-04    2
    # 1  2020-10-23    1
    # 5  2020-10-29    2
    # 2  2020-11-05    1
    # 4  2020-11-13    2
    # 3  2020-11-14    1

print('#' * 50)   
# drop the time with tag 1 & 2 more than 1 times
df3['diff'] = df3['tag'].diff()
cond = df3['diff'] == 0
df3 = df3[~cond]
print('drop the time with tag 1 & 2 more than 1 times')
print(df3)

    #          time  tag  diff
    # 0  2020-08-04    2   NaN
    # 1  2020-10-23    1  -1.0
    # 5  2020-10-29    2   1.0
    # 2  2020-11-05    1  -1.0
    # 4  2020-11-13    2   1.0
    # 3  2020-11-14    1  -1.0

print('#' * 50)   
# make the first row'tag is 1(starttime)
if df3.iloc[0, 1] == 2:
    df_append = pd.DataFrame([{'time':np.nan, 'tag':1}])
    df3 = df_append.append(df3)

# make the last row'tag is 2(stoptime) 
if df3.iloc[0, 1] == 1:
    df3 = df3.append([{'tag':2}])
print(f'''
make the first row'tag is 1(starttime)
make the last row'tag is 2(stoptime) 
{df3}
''')
    #          time  tag  diff
    # 0         NaN    1   NaN
    # 0  2020-08-04    2   NaN
    # 1  2020-10-23    1  -1.0
    # 5  2020-10-29    2   1.0
    # 2  2020-11-05    1  -1.0
    # 4  2020-11-13    2   1.0
    # 3  2020-11-14    1  -1.0
    # 0         NaN    2   NaN

print('#' * 50)      
df1n = df3.query('tag == 1').reset_index(drop=True)
df2n = df3.query('tag == 2').reset_index(drop=True)
df1n.columns = ['starttime', 'tag', 'diff']
df2n.columns = ['stoptime', 'tag', 'diff']

df3n = pd.concat([df1n['starttime'], df2n['stoptime']],axis=1)
print('result:\n', df3n)

    #     starttime    stoptime
    # 0         NaN  2020-08-04
    # 1  2020-10-23  2020-10-29
    # 2  2020-11-05  2020-11-13
    # 3  2020-11-14         NaN
```